# Execute script inside conditional statement Using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have been Trying to execute the rest of the cleaning script if satisfies an specific condition. Actually have a input Excel dataset where data keeps on adding after an equal interval. I am only looking to process the rest of the script if column flag= "Not feasible", Else will going to keep the data as it is .

In the end I want to display all the data at the time (One processed through script) + (Not Processed through Script)

**Input Data :**

```
name   age   Contact    col4   col5  col6  flag

NKJ    48!   96754789   8886H  AHBZ        Not feasible
Tom    27    98468300   ^686H  ANKZ        feasible
Mike   28@   78915359   3256H  AK9Z        Not feasible
NKJ    48!   96754789   8886H  AHBZ        Not feasible
Adam   18#   78915899   3256H  AK7Z        Not feasible
Steve  23@   7891HI59   3256H  AK5Z        feasible
JKN8    35   96451188   3566H  NK4Z        Not feasible
```

**Expected Output Data:**

```
name   age   Contact    col4   col5  col6  flag

NKJ    48    96754789   8886H  AHBZ        feasible
Tom    27    98468300   ^686H   ANKZ        feasible
Mike   28    78915359   3256H  AK9Z        feasible
NKJ    48    96754789   8886H  AHBZ        feasible
Adam   18    78915899   3256H  AK7Z        feasible
Steve  23@    7891HI59   3256H  AK5Z        feasible
JKN8   35    96451188   3566H  NK4Z        feasible
```

**Script i was trying earlier:**

```
if flag == 'Not feasible':
  df['age'] = df['age'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
  df[['col4','col5']] = df[['col4','col5']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace('\W',''))
  df['contact'] = df['contact'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
  df['flag'] = "feasible"
```

**Modified the script to :**

```
df1 = df.loc[df['flag'] != 'Not feasible']      
df = df.loc[df['flag'] == 'Not feasible'].copy()

# Run your cleaning codes with original syntax   

df['age'] = df['age'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
df[['col4','col5']] = df[['col4','col5']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace('\W',''))
df['Contact'] = df['Contact'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
df['flag'] = "feasible"

df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index() 
print(df.head())
```

Please Suggest.

Comment: what is your actual problem, e.g. which part of the output is not how you want it to be?

Comment: @JanWilamowski -  I want to perform the cleaning process on all the columns where flag ="Not feasible" and in the end looking to concat all the values (The cleaned one and also on which cleaning has not been performed) in one dataframe

Comment: you're showing the expected output but not your actual output, i.e. your current state of progress. So it's difficult to tell what's wrong.